# how to get jena to produce json-ld with embedded object, stripping out the blank node id?

Tags: jena, json-ld

How to get json json-ld serialization to produce clean embedded object that strip out blank node identifier such as instead of

```
{ 
  "@id" : "biodata:20200005793263#relation-annotation-2101" ,
  "@type" : "Annotation" ,
  "body" : 
   { 
       "@id" : "_:b230" ,
       "@type" : "biomed:DirectRegulation" ,
       "biomed:effect" : "positive" ,
   }
}
```

i want to get

```
{ 
  "@id" : "biodata:20200005793263#relation-annotation-2101" ,
  "@type" : "Annotation" ,
  "body" : 
   { 
    "@type" : "biomed:DirectRegulation" ,
    "biomed:effect" : "positive" ,
   }
}
```